# Add predecessor to all tasks "x" number of tasks before it - Microsoft Project

Tags: ms-project

Currently scheduling a 26 level building, and all 26 levels follow the same schedule. For example:

Level A

-Task A

-Task B

-Task C

Level B

-Task A

-Task B

-Task C

Task X occurs on each level and it's ID is 55+/- the level after/before it. Is there a way I can add a predecessor to all of the tasks in the schedule at once to reflect this? I.e. "=taskid-55" as a predecessor? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to copy the values in the *Predecessors* column in MS Project and paste in an Excel Spreadsheet. Then use a formula to append the predecessor you want to add to each cell.

[image: Excel with formula]

Then copy/paste back into MS Project.

If you don't want to go through this manual process, I know of at least one third-party add-in for MS Project that has the ability to add common predecessor to a bunch of tasks at once. [You can check them out here](https://ssitools.com).